# zlib miniunzip fails to open zip files

Tags: c++, zlib

I installed zlib 1.2.8 and built the miniunzip and minizip projects to test creating and opening a zip.

I built as debug on visual studio 2010 32 bit, with the debug dll zlibwapid .

Minizip worked fine to create a zip file however miniunzip failed to open the zipfile created, and looking in miniunz.c the failure is because:
`uf = unzOpen2_64(zipfilename,&ffunc);` returns 0.

I saw the code is wrapped as follows in defines:

```
#ifdef USEWIN32IOAPI
    fill_win32_filefunc64A(&ffunc);
    uf = unzOpen2_64(zipfilename,&ffunc);
#else
     uf = unzOpen64(zipfilename);
#endif
```

On a hunch I changed the define at the top to:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
//#define USEWIN32IOAPI  //disabled this
#include "iowin32.h"
#endif
```

Now mininunzip works fine but I dont really know why.  Anyone know if this is a known bug , I couldnt find any information about it.

Thanks

Comment: Please send bug and fix to zlib@gzip.org.